# Display ID and Value in DropDown using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

There is a requirement of displaying both PackageID, and PackageName in a dropdown, so that customer can select the package for recharge.

As per the current code, PackageName is visbile using DataTextFiled property , which has been set in markup.

Please help to display both PackageID, and Package Name, and go through below codes-

DataBase-

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PackageMaster](
        [PackageID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [PackageName] [varchar](50) NULL
    ) ON

 [PRIMARY]

Create Proc UspGetPackage
As
Begin
Select PackageID,PackageName from PackageMaster
End
```

> --------------------------------------------------Design-------------------------------

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PackageRequest.aspx.cs" Inherits="PackageRequest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Select Package:</b></td>&nbsp
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLPackage" runat="server" DataTextField="PackageName" DataValueField="PackageID"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td><b>Select Sequence:</b></td>&nbsp
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLPakcageSequence" runat="server" DataTextField="SequenceValue" DataValueField="SequenceID"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> ----------------------CodeBehind---------------

```
private DataSet GetData(string SPName, SqlParameter SPParameter)
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SPName, con);
    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    if (SPParameter != null)
    {
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(SPParameter);
    }

    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(DS);
    return DS;

}



protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DDLPackage.DataSource = GetData("UspGetPackage",null);
            DDLPackage.DataBind();

            ListItem lstPkg = new ListItem("--Select Package--","-1");
            DDLPackage.Items.Insert(0,lstPkg);

            //DDLPakcageSequence.DataSource = GetData("UspGetPkgSequence",null);
            //DDLPakcageSequence.DataBind();

            //ListItem pkgsequence = new ListItem("--Select Sequence--", "-1");
            //DDLPakcageSequence.Items.Insert(0, pkgsequence);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concat two columns in  stored procedure.

```
Select CONCAT(PackageID,' ', PackageName ) AS PackageID_PackageName, PackageID,PackageName from PackageMaster
```

In .aspx change `DataTextField="PackageName"` to `DataTextField="PackageID_PackageName"`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLPackage" runat="server" DataTextField="PackageID_PackageName" DataValueField="PackageID"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Thanks It worked as expected. Furthermore, I want to implement validation on drop-down so that at if doesn't select anything, it doesn't allow to submit form. In this program, I am adding a list-item at run time "--Select Package--", which by default is being submitted with -1 value.

Comment: It is very easy. Follow this. https://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2008/10/dropdownlist-example-how-to-validate.html. Please up-vote my answer